# Adding permissions to API with a custom auth backend

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am working on a chat website using Djangorestframework, and the way of submitting a message in it is done using a `GenericAPIView` and the serializer of the `Message` model.

The `MessageSerializer` gets a `User` and the content, and I want to restrict submitting messages in the name of a user to only that user, so users won't be able to post messages in the name of other users.

The way I thought was best is to check inside the `post` method of the `GenericAPIView` for a match between the author of the message and the currently authenticated user. The problem is that I have a custom auth backend, so for some reason, `request.user` is `AnonnymousUser`, even when I set the default authentication of DRF to `SessionAuthentication`, I still get the same results.

`request.user` does return the current user in normal django views, but not in DRF ones.

Is there a better way to achieve this? Or is there something I am doing wrong? I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Post your custom auth backed

Comment: My custom auth backend just implements `Authenticate` which returns a `User` or `None`, and `get_user` which returns the same.@itzmeontv

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if you call the django.contrib.auth.login() in the login_view.

Comment: `request.user` does return the current user in normal django views, but not in DRF ones. Which login_view are you talking about?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests , or I misunderstood your question. In my project, I has a custom login_view to support both username and email login, so you have to check the user then use login() func to set session

Comment: I have a login view which calls authenticate() and then login(). After the user has logged in, I am able to call request.user and get the user. The problem is that the post() method in a `GenericAPIView`, gets a `request` argument, and this particular request.user returns `AnonnymousUser`

Comment: that's really wield , but I think the best way to set message's sender is , let MessageSerializer's  sender field to be readonly and default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()

Comment: Sounds good.. I'll give this a try and report back in a few days. Thanks.

Comment: I tried that and still got `AnonnymousUser`... In all the other views which aren't of DRF I do get the right user for some reason